# Building z3 with Visual studio command prompt on Windows x64

Tags: python, visual-studio, z3, nmake

I downloaded z3 from gitHub https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3, I decide to download the source code in order to have all the files.

I have followed the instruction in the file README.md for installing z3 on windows x64, but it didn't work. Then, I have  tried different command Prompt to launch "scripts/mk_make.py -x" as I saw in suggestions around the web.
But the output is always the same:

`<Generating src\util\z3_version.h from src\util\z3_version.h.in                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):File "scripts/mk_make.py", line 16, in <module>                                  update_version()                                                                                                File "C:\Program Files (x86)\z3\scripts\mk_util.py", line 2750, in update_version mk_version_dot_h(major, minor, build, revision)                                                                        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\z3\scripts\mk_util.py", line 2772, in mk_version_dot_h                                configure_file(version_template, version_header_output,                                                              File "C:\Program Files (x86)\z3\scripts\mk_util.py", line 3426, in configure_file    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as f:                                                                                 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'src\\util\\z3_version.h'>.`

Does anyone know what I have to do?

Thanks a lot if someone will answer me!!

Comment: I think as a normal user, you don't have write permission to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\` You can chose to move it to a different location or you need to run everything as administrator.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried to run as administrator but the result still the same.

Comment: In the same command prompt, if `echo abc > "c:\Program Files (x86)"\blah.txt` throws a permission error, then you don't have permission. If that succeeds, the Z3 scripts should be able to create new files too. In general though, you'll be happier if you keep the source files outside of c:\Program Files...

Comment: ok, I'll retry moving Z3 in an other directory! Thanks a lot!